# How to factory reset Galaxy Note 10.1 from Odin

Tags: factory-reset, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, heimdall

My Note 10.1 (N8010) won't boot - sticks at the "Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1" logo.  Power+VolUp does not take me to the recovery (just reboots), but Power+VolDown *does* take me to "ODIN MODE", so I presume my options are limited to things I can do from ODIN MODE.  Fortunately there is no data on the tablet that I need.

I would like to perform a factory reset.

My best guess is that I need to erase the cache (and possibly data) partitions.  Can I erase these from ODIN?

If I need a cache.img or other images, where can I get or how can I create one?

I use Linux so I cannot use Kies.  I have Heimdall which appears to do this sort of thing.

I have flashed TWRP (using ODIN) in the hope that it would boot into that recovery, but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Flashing a whole factory firmware should automatically perform a wipe afterwards. If that doesn't work then you have trouble.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Where can I get a whole factory firmware image, please?

Comment: @MarkSmith SamMobile: [link](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-N8010)

Comment: Thanks again. I've flashed it using the instructions at https://gnoshmeness.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/rooting-and-flashing-custom-rom-using-ubuntu-heimdall-and-generally-useful-noob-info/ and that file (unzipped and the result untarred) but it's exactly the same, and I'm not convinced it's performed any "wipe" other than writing over the various partitions (which is not all of them).

Comment: @MarkSmith I don't know for certain... Most if not all Samsung devices I had would automatically boot into recovery immediately after flashing via Odin. Could be related to you using Heimdall?

Comment: It does reboot after flashing - but into its stuck-a the-logo state, not into the recovery. I guess this is the problem - it can't run the recovery. Strange.

Comment: @MarkSmith Out of ideas - I'm thinking hardware faults.  +1 for attention.